# automatically occupy free space

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one android app in which there is a layout. In this layout two text view is there and one view in between these text view(view is a line).

Dynamically text get inserted into text view.
I want the line automatically occupy the remaining width.

I can make it by using linear layout and giving weight to each view but in this case width will we fixed in some ratio.

How I make this possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tViewMassageOnLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tViewArrawTowardsLeft"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="RESPONSE"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tViewMassageOnLeft"
    android:background="#456765" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tViewMassageOnRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="REQUEST"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have combination of LinearLayout includes above 3 views

Comment: If you are putting all components horizontally then set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` It will adjust it automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffffff" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tViewMassageOnLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="RESPONSE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tViewMassageOnLeft"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tViewMassageOnRight"
        android:background="#456765" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tViewMassageOnRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="REQUEST"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This will be the result.

[image]